# Numpy Errors when Installing Tensor Flow on Raspbian

Tags: installation, python, raspberry-pi

I was attempting to install tensor flow on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian using the directions here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

I reached Step 2 and noticed that suddenly there were no directions for Raspbian.  Since it was only 'recommended' I skipped to step 3 and proceeded.  Only on the last step (confirm install of Tensor Flow) did I run into an issue.  When I ran:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

The output was:

`ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.`

I uninstalled Numpy using the package manager and ran a version check that informed me Numpy was not installed.  To detect the version I used:

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
```

When attempting to use the command to verify the Tensor Flow install above, I again got the same error, though the system tells me there is no numpy installed.

I found no way to uninstall "again", so I'm stuck at this point, not sure what I can do to make this work.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, running the following (from cat /etc/os-release):

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

My apologies if this is a duplicate.  I did a search for my error and didn't find what I was looking for.  Also, I am generally pretty technically savvy, but this is a new world for a career windows user, so please be specific and if you can explain how a given solution works it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I encountered the same issue today. tensorflow is compatible with only some numpy versions. I did solve the issue by installing numpy 1.16 through pip:

```
pip install --user numpy==1.16
```

or, if you use python3,

```
pip3 install --user numpy==1.16
```